# Using COUNTIF excluding duplicates in the same column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like a formula to be able to calculate a COUNTIF function, but ignoring duplicate values in the same column. My sheet looks something like this:

[image]

For example, if I were to count the number of occurrences of "Grass" it would return a result of 4, ignoring the duplicates in columns C and D.

Link to this spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110De2u6mKLT7SOTfaXN6EZVqgD35pEeeog9o5WWn5bs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it'd be nice if you left the sheet stay public (at least View Only) for future readers of this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new sheet on your sample spreadsheet called MK.Idea.  There you will find this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(UNIQUE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!B1:G1&"|"&Sheet1!B2:G),"|")),"Grass"))
```

That uses UNIQUE and a SPLIT(Flatten technique to isolate the "grass" values that are duplicates *in a given column*